# Package id platform: android-O not available

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

While trying to clone [Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html) sample from github, project can't able to sync and give below error.
Android studio give *package unavailable*, which can't able to install missing platform (android o).

[image: Android O missing package]

I am using android studio 2.3 and cloning android o example: https://developer.android.com/preview/o-samples.html#nc

Can any one suggest, how can I able to run cloned example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add the Android O items to Android Studio 2.3, I had to temporarily switch to the Canary channel in Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio Channel Settings]

Then, in the SDK Manager, I could download the O Developer Preview items:

[image: SDK Manager, Showing O Developer Preview 1]

...along with the 26-rc1 build tools, platform tools, and emulator:

[image: SDK Manager, Showing SDK Tools Tab]

That should get you past your current problems.

That project is messed up, in that it refers to a `@mipmap/ic_launcher` that does not exist. You need to get rid of `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` from the `<application>` element of `Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, after which the app appears to work.

Comment: Thanks you sir for your replay. I am trying and back to you.

Comment: Great. Switching to the canary Chanel and downloaded android o sdk components. Then resolved icon issue and now I am able to run example.

Comment: Mark I am on Android Studio 2.4 Preview 3, I have already downloaded Android O SDK Platform and Android Sdk Build-tools 26-rc1, but still unable to download the package and it's showing the same alert.

Comment: @PareshMayani: I do not know what to tell you. I never use a preview edition of Android Studio, and so I have not tried 2.4 Preview 3. Sorry!

Comment: I just try canary version to stay updated what's coming up and I was curious to know what is coming up with Android O and new studio version. Thanks though for replying back. Appreciate