# Can't find Android 8.0-8.1 (Oreo) API 26-27 ARM System Images

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

Are there anywhere Android 8.0 (Oreo) API 26 and Android 8.1 (Oreo) API 27 ARM System images (ARM, not x86 Intel) for AVD Manager? Thanks.

Unofficial? Beta? Alpha? Any?

Comment: There can't really be unofficial ones, as the source to ODP1 has not been released for somebody to build one from scratch. I haven't seen an official one. I am not certain why there is a delay.

Comment: Be sure to download AS 2.4: https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html#ptb

Comment: I'm talking about system images (ARM, not x86 Intel) for AVD Manager, not system images for a range of hardware devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960007/package-id-platform-android-o-not-available

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That link only mentions 2.3.3 and 3.0, are you sure there is such a thing as 2.4?

Comment: @nasch On the date that I posted the link, yes there was such a thing as 2.4. Since then, Google decided that the next release would be 3.0 instead. Now that Android O has been officially released as Android Oreo, you can download the development APIs and system images directly with the most recent version of Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare The source to 8.0 (Oreo) API 26 has been released

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you can't download ARM system images, only Intel

Comment: @AlexanderSavin did you ever figure out why the arm system images aren't available for api 26? I see them available for android-25.

Comment: @BrianAnderson No, I don't. I didn't read any official comments from Google or other sources.

Comment: This is weird. Still cannot find Oreo ARM images in AVD Manager...

Comment: As of 2020, it appears to no longer be supported. Which is a shame for those of us working with native libs like ffmpeg because that kinda forces us to only use physical devices

Answer (score 2):

The ARM images for API 26 and 27 are not available yet. ARM images available till API 25 only.

**Note:**
Google recommended an x86 system image on an x86 host for better emulation performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggestion,

please check [https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/64-bit#test-64-bit-hardware][1]

They have given how to install new abi along with apk to your device-
:: Command Line

## A successful install:

> adb install --abi armeabi-v7a YOUR_APK_FILE.apk
> Success

## If your APK does not have the 64-bit libraries:

> adb install --abi arm64-v8a YOUR_APK_FILE.apk
> adb: failed to install YOUR_APK_FILE.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

## If your device does not support 64-bit, an emulator, for example:

> adb install --abi arm64-v8a YOUR_APK_FILE.apk
> ABI arm64-v8a not supported on this device

Answer (score -1):

You should build Android sources for specific platform by yourself

Answer (score -1):

Recent updates enabled computers with AMD processors to run Android Emulator and you don't need to install ARM images anymore. Taken from the Android Developers blog:

If you have an AMD processor in your computer you need the following setup requirements to be in place:

> AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
>
> Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher
>
> Android Emulator v27.3.8+
>
> x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD)
>
> Windows 10 with April 2018 Update
>
> Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

And that's it! I strongly recommend reading the whole blog post:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: True but you can only do that with Android 11 images. Android 10, 9, 8, still only x86