# android 8.0 api 26 arm64-v8a system image for emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, arm64, android-8.0-oreo

I dont seem to find system image for arm64-v8a for api 26 android 8.0 oreo from the android studio virtual device manager. There is no image other than x86.

Any information of when will google support or provide the system image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find Android 8.0 (Oreo) API 26 ARM System Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017539/cant-find-android-8-0-oreo-api-26-arm-system-images)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the ARM images for API 26 are not available yet. You will have to wait for it.

Comment: There is still no ARM support for API 26 (Android 8) and now Android 9 is released. It looks like Android emulator will not support ARM anymore? Some apps only work with this architecture so it would be good to have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue against the Android development team to provide API 26 ARM emulator images here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130023365

If having this support is important to you, you should go star that issue