# Where are the Android 8, 9 & 10 ARM images for Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android, arm, emulation

I can only select up to Android 7.1.1:

[image]

What gives, Google?

And with Android 7.1.1 you don't seem to be able to sign into Google services, which also limits functionality:

[image]

Comment: Did you check under the `Recommended` tab ?

Comment: they are not available after API 25. you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/43017539/8809599

Comment: Yes I did check under 'Recommended' @Mayokun - it recommends me to install an x86_64 image, but the app I want to install doesn't have an x86_64 build

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 4.1.1 released in November 2020 includes an AVD with Android 11 that can run ARM-only apps. The release notes explain that this new virtual device can convert AMD instructions (32 bits) into x86 code on the fly, without major loss of performance. Because of that, we may expect future Android Studio emulators to also run ARM apps in a similar way.

AVD running Android 10, 9, 8, as far as I can see, still only support x86 though, and I suspect that will not change, because that would require Google to retroactively apply this new technology to older virtual devices, and I don't think they're ever going to do that.